# Python list into SQL column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have two or more lists, for example:

```
    name = ['Chris', 'John', 'Louis']
    surname = ['Brown', 'Green', 'Red']
    car = ['Audi', 'Mercedes', 'Ferrari']
```

What I'd like to achieve is creating an sql database where every list is a column so that it would be something like: "Chris" in the first line, "Brown" in the second line and "Audi" in the third one - and so on. My actual python script is the following one but I can't figure out how I can save the list:

```
    connection = sqlite3.connect("name.db")                       
    cursor = connection.cursor()                                  
    cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS peopleList")           
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE peopleList(Name TEXT, Surname TEXT, Car TEXT)")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`executemany()`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) like so:

```
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO peopleList (Name, Surname, Car) VALUES (?,?,?)""", 
                   zip(name,surname,car))
```

Comment: I got a traceback error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: @antonioag: oh I see now you're using SQLite3. The question was titled and tagged with MySQL so that confused me. Please see edited answer which should work.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag and thank you for your time. Anyway, no more errors but the file created has 0 rows

Comment: Make sure you do `connection.commit()` after the INSERT statement.